# PivotTable issue on sqlserver- Data getting split to multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I performed a Pivot on an existing table to get the Week data on the Column Titles, however instead of consolidating and giving me the data in just 3 rows, it splitting to multiple rows.
[image]

I am looking to see the data in just 3 rows and not the repetition. 
Please let me know how to g about with this.

This is the query (looks a little messy coz of the details hidden)
[image]

This is the data I get with the Unpivot:
[image]

Expected result after the Pivot is:
[image]

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result (text format only) would helpful.

Comment: Yes I have added the expected result, thanks

Comment: Ok, your desired result make sense but where is your sample raw data ?

Comment: . . . Your query is going to `unpivot`  & `pivot` again with blind `case` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done what I can based on your redacted SQL statement. You just need to group on Department and Type, then aggregate the pivoted values

```
select case when [REDACTED] END as Dept, Type, max([2019W01]) as [2019W01], max([2019W02]) as [2019W02], max([2019W03]) as [2019W03], max([2019W04]) as [2019W04]
from ( select 
   ltrim(rtrim(Plant)) as Plant
  ,cast(ltrim(rtrim(WeekNo)) as varchar) as WeekNo
  ,substring(cast(ltrim(rtrim(WeekNo)) as [REDACTED]
from [REDACTED] ) as a
unpivot 
(Value for Type in (A,B,C)) as sq
pivot (
  min(Value)
  for WeekNo in ([2019W01], [2019W02], [2019W03], [2019W04])
  ) as Pvt
group by Dept, Type
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a lot clearer to me when pivoting data. You only need to copy-paste-replace on one place and you define how you group your columns.

```
SELECT Dept, Type,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W01' THEN [value] END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W02' THEN [value] END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W03' THEN [value] END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W04' THEN [value] END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W05' THEN [value] END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Weekno = '2019W06' THEN [value] END)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Dept, Type
ORDER BY Dept, Type;
```